# His Tag location in gene circuit

Tags: synthetic-biology, protein-folding, gene

I am part of an undergraduate research group and we are trying to produce a protease in an E.coli gene circuit. We are not sure where to place the His tag in our circuit. The sequence is
...OmpA(gene)->linker->his tag->protease->Terminator->res site 
Should the His tag be in this position, before the linker, or after the protease? OmpA is a outer membrane protein that will allow a protein to be taken to, and linked to, the outer membrane of the E.coli. Our fear is that the protease will not fold correctly and will be nonfunctional.

Comment: When you say gene, have you made sure that the stop codon is removed?

Comment: Usually the his-tag should be in the terminal. Why don't you express the protease as a separate cistron?

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages to put His-tag both N and C termini. When you put a tag at a C terminus, you can purify the full length easily. If you are lucky, you could get full length products even if you put a tag at the N terminus. An additional sequence at a C-terminus may disturb functions of some proteins, but in most of cases, it would not be predictable.

Comment: We have removed the stop codon of the gene. We wanted to have the His tag attached to the protease in some way to use as proof of concept that they protease is being expressed on the outer membrane of the E.coli.

Comment: Then what, I think, you should do is put his-tag after the protease. Is the C-terminal of Omp-A on the outside?

Comment: OmpA is a outer membrane protein so it will bring the protease to the outside of the cell. I'm not sure I fully understand your question. There are other parts of the sequence before the OmpA. OmpA will be on the outside of the cell.

Comment: @KellyEckartt got it. I just wanted to know if the protease would be outside the cell (Can you add this to your question?). C-terminal tag seems safer, in this case, to me. If your objective is just detection then FLAG-tag may be a better idea.

Comment: Fusing your protease to the C-terminus of the OmpA will not diplay it on the outside of the bacteria because the C-terminus is facing the periplasm (the space between the outer and the inner E coli membrane)